# How to get hold of input file from a flowfile?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a script that gets executed in nifi ExecuteScript processor.

Input to the processor is a flowfile corresponsding to an input xlsx file.

I want to get hold of that xlsx file, so that I can use it to be transferred over the network.

Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by `get hold of that xlsx` ?

Comment: I mean to get content of input xlsx file so that it can be transferred over the network.

Comment: what's the issue then? get content is one of the basic functions in script. share your code and error if you have one.

Comment: because the answer to your question right now - yes it's possible :)

Comment: So if original file is a xslx file, get content would fetch exactly same file?

Comment: if original was xsls and other processors did not change it, then yes, content will be xsls